# Получить железо через php

Tags: php

В общем вопрос состоит в том, можно ли получить код железа средствами пхп?...
Нашел сайт один, там можно привязать своё железо к сайту, что бы не вводить логин пароль...
Вот собственно и вопрос возник

Comment: А там точно к железу привязываются? Сильно в этом сомневаюсь, может ссылку дадите? Не уверен, что через js Это сделать можно, а через php, которое вообще никакого отношения к компу клиента не имеет, этого вообще сделать нельзя (только если к ip, например, привязаться) И может там через плагин какой-то работают? Тогда у них будет доступ к вашему компу и можно хоть что получить

Comment: при привязке из личного кабинета - там так  и написано - Привязка к компьютеру, как еще кроме железа - не нашел. http://agecold.ru/cp/profile/ Раздел "Безопасность"